# Refresh a page, without resending POST data(ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

How to refresh and reload the page without resending the POST data?

I have tried `location.reload()` which works absolutely fine on Chrome(which was the testing environment while development). But IE and Firefox went into an Infinite Loop in JS - reposting a lot of junk/duplicate data.

Note: However, I just want to refresh the page to clear all the form contents. I am also registering a start up script after Submit, that will show the alert message that data was added successfully.

HELP!

Comment: Are you posting the page normally, or through JavaScript/AJAX?

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 6):

```
location.href = location.href + '?' + Math.random();
```

This should work.

Comment: +1, but you also need to check if the '?' all ready exist on href.

Answer (score 5):

In your code add:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to clear the form, why not:

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear Fields">
```

You could also do it using:

```
document.getElementById('<%=form1.ClientID%>').reset();
```

Seems a waste to reload the page unless you need to do something else as well.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following:

`Server.Transfer(Request.RawUrl);`

Answer (score 2):

The following will solve your problem:

```
Server.Transfer(Request.RawUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `location.reload(true)`. This "hard" reloads the page ..

Answer (score 0):

I've try reload too, and reload(true) both not exactly doing what I wanted.

I've seen that Location Object have other method (than reload) since I wanted to request the page in "get" I just did:

```
location.assign(window.location);
```

So far seem to be doing what I want, reload the same page without submitting again values. My use case is an ajax call to the server when session has expired. I display an error message saying that the session is lost, then I want the page to reload.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.href)
```